# Access 97: table entry to drop off form when a date/time reached

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I like to think i'm not completely useless at creating MS Access databases, but i'm  definitely a failure at the SQL code side.. So as a result i'm not sure whether this is a stupid question or not!
At work i'm trying to add a "news feed" type thing to a Form on the front screen of a database used to find useful information stored in various places. At the moment my workplace is using Office 2007, but Access is the 97 version!!!! As they're only recently realizing it can be used to solve a few of their problems... we're expecting to upgrade the whole of office and access to 2010 soon.

On this database (created using access 97..) there is a "refresh" type button which simply closes and re-opens the form and thus shows the latest info entered onto the "news feed", and this also shows the current time and date. What i'd like to happen is have specific entries drop off after a period of time (which probably wont happen unless refreshed), so for example an entry will have been added regarding some server ammendments being made within the workplace so "certain systems will not be working between 8am and 5pm GMT on 9/1/12" and preferably the person who created this entry could enter a date into the form 24 hours, or even a few days, later and when this date is reached the entry would disappear. I understand this is something that may be achieved using a query but i have no idea where to start.

If anyone can help give me an idea of how to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

I apologise if this is poorly worded or not completely clear, i can elaborate if questions are asked.

many thanks,

Kris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a query like this to return only the entries that are less than 3 days old:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE CreateTime > DateAdd("d", -3, Now())
```

In your form, you can define a timer interval and a timer event handler (see the "Event" tab on the properties window). You could use it to requery your list (`Me!lstNews.Requery`).

In the table you can define the column "CreateTime" as data type "Date/Time" and define its default value as   `=Now()`. This way no text box is required to enter this data.

---

EDIT:

How to configure the timer in an Access Form (time is in milliseconds):

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer
there will be a variety of entries into this newsfeed that will be checked daily by staff when using the database, the entries will have varying levels of importance and will need varying periods of expiry. Some of the notices will be regarding local transport issues and may be needed for 3 days, some may be needed for a week. Is it possible to have a box to enter the amount of days or even have toggle buttons?
the table for the subform showing this info is called "TBL KD Newsfeed", and currently has the fields "Entry Number", "Date", "Time", "Subject", and "Body".

Comment: Either you have an entry NumberOfDays, then change the WHERE clause to `CreateTime > DateAdd("d", -NumberOfDays, Now())` or create a date/time column ExpiresAt and change the clause to `ExpiresAt > Now`.

Comment: Okay, i follow you. Although as i previously mentioned i'm an SQL novice! Silly question but what is the meaning of the "*" on the "SELECT" line?
Thanks again for your response, Kris.

Comment: sorry the * is to select all the fields in the table for the query isnt it. Ok i'll try this out and see where i get, thanks

Comment: Ok it doesn't seem to be working. I'll try to explain what i have and what needs to happen, I have a table called "Newsfeed" which contains "Entry Number" (Autonumber), "Date" (Date/Time), "Time" (Date/Time), "Service" (linked to a table as a combobox to show drop down), "Subject" (as text 250 characters), "Body" (memo), and now "NumberOfDays" (so user can enter number of days to go by until the entry disappears throughquery). If you can walk me through what code is needed to enter into the query and where/what to enter for the timer interval / on timer handles it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The star "*" means, "return all the columns". Instead you could also have a list of columns: `SELECT Title, BodyText, Date FROM ...`.

Comment: The query will not change it will always have a where clause of `WHERE [Newsfeed].[Date] >= DateAdd("d", -NumberOfDays, Date())`

Comment: excellent, i'm following you so far. So in the properties tab of the form where the query will be active i enter the "30000" milliseconds for the Timer Interval, but what is entered into "On Timer" as Event Procedure?
apologies for being incredibly stupid. I am following you so far however.

Comment: would it be:
" SELECT * FROM Newsfeed WHERE [Newsfeed].[Date] >= DateAdd("d", -NumberOfDays, Date()) "
in Event Procedure?

Comment: It depends. If NumberOfDays is a column in your table which is stored for each news entry, then no changes are required in the SQL statement and you only would have to requery the control or form where the news are displayed with `someControl.Requery` or someForm.Requery`. if, however, NumberOfDays is only a textbox that applies to all records then you would have to change the query  and assign it the data source: someControl.ControlSource = "SELECT * FROM Newsfeed WHERE [Newsfeed].[Date] >= DateAdd('d', -" & NumberOfDays & ", Date())". Or someForm.RecordSource = "SELECT ..."

Comment: superb, figured it out and it works fine. how would i do this in hours instead of days?? many thanks,

Comment: See the help for the `DateAdd` function. The first parameter is a string which determines the intervall type. It would "h" for hours.